# Google font loads very weirdly after the deployment to the vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, google-fonts

I have deployed the next js app to the server using vercel. I have referenced the two google fonts in `_document.js`. While I am running the app locally both font load without any problem.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document
{
    static async getInitialProps(ctx)
    {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return { ...initialProps }
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crete+Round&amp;family=Work+Sans:wght@500;600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";
import Banner from "../components/Banner";
import { fetchAPI } from "../lib/api";
import Articles from "../components/Articles";

export default function Home({ articles })
{
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Life Sciencify - Explore the mystery of life with Science! </title>
      </Head>
      <Articles articles={articles} />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps()
{
  const [articlesRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/posts", { populate: ["cover", "category"] })
  ]);

  console.log(articlesRes)

  return {
    props: {
      articles: articlesRes.data
    }
  };
}
```

app.js

```
import Script from "next/script";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import "../styles/globals.css";

import { useEffect } from "react";

import Header from "../components/Header";
import SearchBlock from "../components/SearchBlock";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps })
{
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

After the deployment it is showing the weird behavior.

Initially When I am in the home page the page doesn't load any font.

[image]

Now, when I click the link Post1 or Post 2, it will be redirected to the detail page.
at first font is not loaded in this page too.

[image]

Now, after the page refresh the font gets loaded.

[image]

Now, when I go to the back page in the browser, the home page will have the font loaded. But again when the page is refreshed the font will be gone.

What is the causing the weird behavior?

I am running the application in the next js version of "12.1.6".

Referenced:

1. [google-font-display](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/google-font-display)
2. [font-optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization)

Answer (score 0):

In the _document.js i used two google fonts separately and it is working now.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document
{
    static async getInitialProps(ctx)
    {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return { ...initialProps }
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500;600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crete+Round&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

and in **index.js**, change server side rendering to static props:

```
export async function getStaticProps()
{
  const [articlesRes] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI("/posts", { populate: ["cover", "category"] })
  ]);

  console.log(articlesRes)

  return {
    props: {
      articles: articlesRes.data
    }
  };
}
```

After this changes I deployed to vercel it worked fine, again after some time i changes to `getServerSideProps`, it was not working. So, the culprit was `getServerSideProps` with google font.